# de Waard volume on Fermat

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

Fermat's works were published by Tannery and Henry in four volumes, the last of which appeared in 1912.

An additional volume was edited by de Waard in 1922:

> Fermat, P. Oeuvres de Fermat: Supplément aux tomes I--IV. Documents inédits publiés avec notices sur les nouveaux manuscrits par M.V. De Waard 1922.

I have the pdfs for Tannery's volumes but I can't find one for de Waard.  Does anyone have a pdf for de Waard and/or know where one can find one?

Comment: Ici: https://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/ABR8792.0005.001/8?rgn=full+text;view=pdf

Comment: @PhilHarmsworth, this is just table of contents and introduction (not even all of it).

Comment: try clicking on the "List all pages" link.

Comment: @PhilHarmsworth, they don't have a scan of the manuscript there as far as I could tell but rather extracted text with numerous textual errors (as is common with optical symbol recognition).

Answer (score 1):

A colleague pointed me to a good source for historical documents at https://archive.org but you need to log in there.

Comment: No you don't? I can't remember I ever did.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer, apparently times have changed:-)  They wouldn't let me download anything until I logged in.